# Drupal 7 generated different <img src="path"> to different locations in filesystem - why?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-views

I'm not very familiar to Drupal and there is a behaviour I don't understand.
Some image  go to example: /system/files/styles/produkt_newsevents/private/, some to
/sites/default/files/styles/produkt_promoted/public/.

Well, I found out that the path to /system/files/ is kind of virtual path. It doesn't exist in real.
But why is it (it is generated with a view and a image style) gernerated? Is there a specail thing to do in Drupal, that this path private is generated only in this view? Because I don't realy need this virtual path to public Images.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/core/modules/image/working-with-images

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any /system/files paths are "private" files, meaning the files themselves are served with PHP rather than served via the webserver.  As they're actioned via PHP then can then have permissions applied to them - so perhaps only users with a certain role can view them.

This is why the directory, as you mentioned, doesn't exist - it does exist somewhere, it just doesn't have to (and shouldn't) sit in the webroot (else someone could perhaps *guess* the path directly to it).

As for why some images use it and others don't, this is purely down to implementation.  You can set public/ private at a field level - so perhaps your install has just been set up like this?

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help Pobtastic. Now I found the checkbuttons to set up public or private file locatian in > Structure > Content Types > My content > Manage Fields.
I changed the "Upload destination" from Private files to Public files in my spcific field "IMAGE_LOGO" in the field settings. Now the url path is public.